# A good free ftp plugin for Sublimetext 2

Tags: plugins, ftp, sublimetext2

I am new to Sublimetext and wondering what is a good free FTP plugin to use with it. Thought the editor must have something inbuilt in it. I have seen developers use some sort of FTP plugin with it. Feedback appreciated.

I am on a Mac Moutain Lion so respective solutions would be awesome.

Thanks.

Comment: Funny how an offtopic question gets 50,000+ views. Ahh the line is so blurry

Comment: Not really blurry. Just because a question gets a lot of views doesn't mean it's a suitable question for the site. Software recommendations are not welcome on stackoverflow

Comment: @Rob I hope SO isn't offended

Comment: It's unfortunate when people forget the purpose of the site is to help others with their programming and related problems. Software recommendations surely do that, as long as they are unbiased and list pros/ cons of all that could be used, no?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've been using [SFTP by WBond](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp) and I'm fairly happy with it.

Comment: Thanks for this response, my bad, ya updated the question since looking for a free one.

Comment: It has an indefinite trial, though if you want to keep it free you'll just have to put up with occasional pop-ups, asking you to buy the full version.

Comment: This is a very helpful plugin especially with its straightfoward SFTP features which is quite confusing with clients like Filezilla or eclipse even. Thanks.

Comment: With this plugin do you get to just save a file and it gets uploaded right away?

Comment: @Purefan Yup, every time you save your file it gets pushed to your server.

Comment: I was just looking and it seems that you have to store your ftp password as plain text in the config file.  Something to know.

Comment: If any one cares about an alternative, I started using Fetch as well just for this to securely working with pem keys.

Comment: Tried this, but was hoping for something better for Sublime. Is there an alternative that lets you navigate remote directories and upload files that are not text files?

Answer (score 72):

I use the sftp package that does have an unlimited trial that never expires.  You will have to put up with the occasional nag screen.  Other than that try the ftp package that is listed in the package control.  Very basic and free but may do what you want.  Here is the link to the site [FTPSync on Github](https://github.com/NoxArt/SublimeText2-FTPSync) so that you can read about it before installing.  I have one person in a club I belong to using this ftp code so that when he updates one page each month it auto uploads to the web site.  The user does not have to do anything except open Sublime, add the lines he needs to add and save the page and the site is updated.

Comment: Your first answer, great! Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: This is a good one but now my requirements include SFTP, especially since cloud servers now prefer sftp. So I am marking another one as the answer. Although this should do it  in most case. +1 though.

Comment: @pal4life It was his last answer too :-(

Answer (score 7):

There are a few programs that allow you to synchronize local and remote directories. Personally I use WinSCP - a very good free FTP client with a lot of features. Synchronization is one of them and it works pretty well.

Comment: I just started using the "keep synchronized" feature about three weeks ago.  Works really well.  You just have to be careful to do an initial bi-directional "prompted" synchronization first.  Otherwise you risk having files deleted off the server that aren't represented locally (meaning the synchronization works... just be sure you're prepared to get what you asked for!).

Answer (score 4):

There is an alternative solution.  I use [SFTP Net Drive](http://sftpnetdrive.com/) works very well on Windows, (the free version match my needs) then just mount your app folder as any 'normal' folder.

Comment: This sounds good, although I am on a Mac so this does not work for me.

Comment: give a try to Expandrive , but i'm not sure is there a free version :
http://www.expandrive.com/expandrive

Comment: free for home use is DirectNet Drive [link](http://directnet-drive.net). Fully emulates local disk behavior for the mounted sites with support FTP, WebDAV, SFTP

Answer (score 1):

You can use eq Webdrive, but better disable indexing files in Sublime, otherwise sublime will be try download/index/list all files from ftp.

---

Yes you can use other solution but there is nothing better that Notepad++ FTP, so sad